# Calling function between modules in same directory in python

Tags: python, function, module

I have two modules in the same directory, one has the function in it. I am trying to call the function into my another module, but I am facing AttributeError

module1:

```
from tank import cal as c

def water():
    lev1=c.rec1
    lev2=c.rec2
    lev3=c.rec3
    print(lev1)
    print(lev2)
    print(lev3)
```

module2:

```
    from tank import level as lv

    a=input("enter the number")
    rec1=a[1:5]
    rec2=a[5:9]
    rec3=a[9:13]
    lv.water()
```

Error:

```
    AttributeError: module 'tank.level' has no attribute 'water'
```

Directory Structure:

`Data
     --tank
       --__init__.py
       --cal.py
       --level.py`

Comment: `tank` is the package which has both the modules

Comment: module 1: posted  is `tank.level` and module 2: is `cal`

Comment: Show the directory structure for these module

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two modules that are importing each other! You shouldn't have cyclical imports like this; one way to fix this is to have the water() function accept some arguments instead of directly trying to import values from the other module.

```
def water(lev1, lev2, lev3):
    print(lev1)
    print(lev2)
    print(lev3)
```

Comment: you want me to replace `rec` to `lev`

Comment: Hey @Nithya! what @Michael is trying to say is, when you run cal.py interpreter goes on to import level.py, which in turn contains import cal, so it goes to cal again.. then level again. Read about circular imports in python.  https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/

Comment: Thanks guys for the info. That gave me the knowledge what I was looking for